# Why use a specialised template class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

This occured in the line of thought following [Template specialization or conditional expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285032/template-specialization-or-conditional-expressions).

I am using template specialisation in a project of mine and came across this example from Stroustrup: [Matrix.h](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Matrix/Matrix.h), where he declares a MatrixBase template class

```
template<class T> class Matrix_base
```

for common elements and a Matrix template class

```
template<class T = double, int D = 1> class Matrix
```

as a "prop" (whatever that is) for specialisations. He declares the constructor as private so that only specialisations can be instanciated. These are declared:

```
template<class T> class Matrix<T,1> : public Matrix_base<T> {...};
template<class T> class Matrix<T,2> : public Matrix_base<T> {...};
template<class T> class Matrix<T,3> : public Matrix_base<T> {...};
```

My question is: In this case, what is the advantage of specialisation? Obviously there is no code that the three specialisations have in common, so why not cut out the general template and declare:

```
template<class T> class Matrix_1<T> : public Matrix_base<T> {...};
template<class T> class Matrix_2<T> : public Matrix_base<T> {...};
template<class T> class Matrix_3<T> : public Matrix_base<T> {...};
```

?

Comment: what if at one point in your code you get a compile time integer telling you which matrix to use...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Because by having the second template parameter, one allows for specializations **as well as** a general, non-specialized implementation. So</strike>

```
Matrix<float, 1000> m;
```

might do something reasonable but non specialized, whereas you would have to define a `Matrix_1000<T>`.
**Edit**: the first point applies in general, but not to this particular case, where the general case has a private constructor.

Furthermore, it allows you to do stuff like

```
Matrix<double, SOME_CONSTANT> m;
```

which you cannot do with your `_N` solution.

Comment: I get your 2nd point, which is similar to PlasmaHH's comment on my question. Concerning the 1st argument: With the constructor of the general case declared as private `Matrix<float, 1000> m;` will lead to a compile time error.

Comment: ah, ok... I thought I had missed something ;)

Answer (score 2):

Basically the answer is that you can use the template in generic code. You can use a compile time constant to change the behavior of the program, or you can write generic code that will handle different versions of the `Matrix` class that could not be handled if the types had different names:

```
template <typename T, int D>
void print( std::ostream& o, Matrix<T,D> const & m ) { ...
```

That is, even though you need to explicitly create the different types, the specialization mechanism allows you to provide a *single* name that can be used generically to manage the different types as if they are just variants of one single type.